# Server error VQMOD Opencart permissions: You don't have permission to access /shop/vqmod/install on this server

Tags: vqmod

I have a website running with a content management system running in the root of my website. I have installed the latest version of Opencart in a sub-directory called "shop" - so www.domain.com/shop/

Everything works fine and I can use Opencart as expected.

I need to install VQmod so have uploaded the files to the root of the shop folder, I have set the correct permissions trying 755 and 777 but with no luck.

Every time I go to www.domain.com/shop/vqmod/install I get a 403 error.

Same with  www.domain.com/shop/vqmod/

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /shop/vqmod/install on this server.
Apache Server at domain.com Port 80
```

My .hta file is pretty much standard apart from taking out the index.php? out of the urls and a rewrite rule to say change the home link.

```
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}? [R=301,L]
```

I am running on an apache server mentioned in error and on plesk control panel. I am stuck!

Also I have a .hta file in my very root where the cms files are how do I ensure that does not conflict the with opencart website.

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this? Am experiencing same issues

Comment: getting same issue, can anyone have any solution for this

Comment: did anyone resolve this?

Comment: Yeh in your .hta file change the word "disallow" to "allow"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found it at last....
.htaccess in of vqmod is set to Deny from all. change it to allow and it should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Did you also change the file permissions for your www.domain.com/shop/index.php and www.domain.com/shop/admin/index.php files during vqmod installation?

This is vital as changes are made to these files during the auto-installation process.

Comment: I have made the changes to them yes, i have done the manual install as opposed to the installer to get it to work. The files get created in the cache folder and i have installed the vqmod manager and can see the vqmods installed however if i go to shop/vqmod/install i should see a message saying that vqmod has been installed shouldnt i?

Comment: Yes - you should see 'VQMOD ALREADY INSTALLED!'

Have you tried running a vqmod to see if it works correctly?